# Request behind load-balancer

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have nginx server and have information about connected users.
Also I can send 'GET' request with connection id to server and disconnect my users. BUT, I can't send request to selected pod, because load-balance redirect request to another pod. I decide just send request to all pods, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll need to change your approach and use a kind of control plane on which pods subscribe to receive control messages. As you write the load balancer redirect to another pod in every request as this is its primary function.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, for fast answer. Not sure I understood correctly, can you write some example or explain like for child?